# Transforming None to empty list pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, nonetype

I have a pandas data frame looking as follows (only firs 21 rows displayed)

```
<bound method DataFrame.to_dict of     docdb_family_id                                   newa_cited_docdb  \
0            569328  [  596005  4321416  5802640  6031690  6043910 ...   
1            574660  [ 5956195 11260528 22181831 22437920 22642946 ...   
2           1187498  [ 5855196  7755392 11183886 22894980 24648618 ...   
3           1226468  [ 3573464  6279285  6294985  6542463  6981930 ...   
4           1236571  [ 2777078  2826073  5944733 10484188 11052747 ...   
5           1239098  [ 5777407 10417156 23463145 23845079 24397163 ...   
6           1239277  [ 4136523 12578497 21994155 22418792 22626616 ...   
7           1239483  [21722194 23841261 23870348 24749080 26713455 ...   
8           1239622  [ 3770167  9249538 20340153 21805004 21826650 ...   
9           1239624  [ 3773931 10400885 23825854 24863945 24904226 ...   
10          1239749  [ 6245732  6270984  6282047  6313094  6323632 ...   
11          1334477  [1331950 5937719 5950928 6032897 6737094 8103287]   
12          1340405  [22536768 23111794 23827356 24148953 24483064 ...   
13          1340418  [ 4096597  6452385  9164095 19820980 22468583 ...   
14          1340462  [ 6273193  6365448  9349940 10531948 13589721 ...   
15          1340471  [ 3770297  6285357 21272262 21883292 22392025 ...   
16          1340485              [21808322 25167492 25401922 26858065]   
17          1340488  [ 6293130 12621423 12977043 14043576 14524083 ...   
18          1340508  [21923978 23414619 23700077 23916998 23917011 ...   
19          1340519  [ 3029629  3461742  8589904 10338953 10633369 ...   
20          1340541                                               None   

         paperid  fronteer  distance  
0            NaN         0       NaN  
1            NaN         0       NaN  
2            NaN         0       NaN  
3            NaN         0       NaN  
4            NaN         0       NaN  
5            NaN         0       NaN  
6            NaN         0       NaN  
7            NaN         0       NaN  
8            NaN         0       NaN  
9            NaN         0       NaN  
10           NaN         0       NaN  
11           NaN         0       NaN  
12           NaN         0       NaN  
13           NaN         0       NaN  
14           NaN         0       NaN  
15           NaN         0       NaN  
16           NaN         0       NaN  
17           NaN         0       NaN  
18           NaN         0       NaN  
19           NaN         0       NaN  
20  1.998989e+09         1       0.0  >
```

or like this, if you prefer:

[image]

What I would like to do is to transform each None value in newa_cited_docdb into an empty list [].

The final data frame should hence have a [] rather than a None in row 20 for column newa_cited_docdb.

I have already tried this:

```
df_final_minimal['newa_cited_docdb'].explode().groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x if x.all() !='None' else [])
```

without success. I also tried with None rather than 'None'.

Thank you

Comment: When you run `to_dict`, you have to execute it: `df.to_dict()`

Comment: Why can't you just replace `None` with `[]` in your column?

Comment: if you dont mind recreating your column, something like `df['colname'] = [[] if lst is None else lst for lst in df.colname]`

Comment: Thank you all for the kind comments. I am sorry I did not execute to_dict. I will edit the thread accordingly. I don't know the reason why I cannot do it since it seems that the type is a Nonetype. I will try also to create the new column according to the suggestion of @dermen